# Can spring create a new schema (using flyway) at startup and then connect to it via default datasource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

My spring-boot app has following properties set,

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my-schema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.flyway.createSchemas=true
spring.flyway.schemas=my-schema
```

The schema 'my-schema' does not pre-exist and I would want for it to be created by flyway and then be used by spring-boot app to sping up HikarCP datasource.

If I run the application with the above configurations I get the following error upon startup:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
Unable to obtain connection from database: Unknown database 'my-schema'
```

Now, if I change,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/
```

The application starts up perfectly and creates the schema. However, when it tries to query any table the thrown exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Flyway with a URL that's used purely for migrations and then configure your app to use a different URL. Something like this:

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my-schema
```

You'll also need to provide credentials for the Flyway-specific connection to the database using `spring.flyway.user` and `spring.flyway.password`.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Thank you Andy. However, there is just a small catch. Whenever you set `spring.flyway.url` you also need to separately set `spring.flyway.user` & `spring.flyway.password`

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer to that effect.